# Can levels be saved and shared offline?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I'm thinking about buying Super Mario Maker, but am worried about what will become of the game some years from now, when Nintendo shut down its servers. Sure, we will still be able to create new courses and enjoy them, but we may not be able to play another person's courses anymore and true gems of level design will be lost forever.

Is it possible to download courses to the Wii U's HD or even an external one, so they can be played offline? In case positive, is there a limit to how many you can download?

For that matter, is it possible to share a level with someone else without internet? E.g. via a SD card or password that recreates the course.

Comment: I would suggest specifically making this question about how to share levels without the internet since it seems to be your main worry. That is answerable and does not anything we have know way of knowing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The title was changed to what was suggested by Mike Kellog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download courses.  When you view a course's information in the online mode, you can click Download instead of Play and it will save a copy of it to your WiiU's internal drive.

I'm not sure if there's a limit to the number of levels you can download.

Having said that, I don't think the game has any way to move them between consoles offline.

Comment: Actually, I should check after work today if there's any way to copy levels onto my SD card from the WiiU's data management thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can save levels offline, but you can't share them. (Or upload them) you need to be online to upload your levels

Answer (score -2):

Backup/save data to a SD card for Mario Maker, then simply load the save data.

All your courses will be there but make sure you back up friends courses before using in case it overrides them.

You can also bypass the storage limit using this method when you fill up all your level slots or download slots. Back up to a SD card, USB flash drive or external hard drive and then start over with all empty slots.

Whenever you want you can access old ones by backing up new ones and loading old save data. Best to fill all your slots with courses first and label your backups so you can tell the courses in your backups.

Comment: also suggest this option of actual course back up to storage to nintendo via 800-255-3700 they take user feedback into account when they make decisions and this is a good idea to be able to actually just export courses rather than havingto back up the whole games save data.

Comment: Please, format your answer to make it readable and use proper punctuation and spelling. You make it hard on everyone to understand what your answer is.